# How can I use scientific notation in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

Here is how I tried to concisely write the number 1 million in Erlang:

```
$ erl
1> 1e6.
* 3: syntax error before: e6
```

Is there a ready-made way to do it, better than

```
1> math:pow(10,6).
1.0e6
```

?

Answer (score 3):

It's staring me in the face in the output of `math:pow`:

```
Eshell V12.1.2  (abort with ^G)
1> 2.3e-3.
0.0023
```

Answer (score 0):

That's it. The answer to your question is exactly what Erlang REPL gave to you. Scientific notation is only available for floats, not integers, so you always have to have some decimals in your number.

For instance, `1.0e6` is a `1000000.0` (float), not the `1000000` (integer). And for relatively small numbers [(up to +/-9007199254740992.0, ~1.0e16)](https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#term-comparisons) you can cast them into an integers using the `erlang:trunc/1` function, but for bigger values, it might lose the precision:

```erlang
1> trunc(1.0e6).
1000000
2> trunc(1.0e100). %% 1 Googol
10000000000000000159028911097599180468360808563945281389781327557747838772170381060813469985856815104
3> 1_000000000_000000000_000000000_000000000_000000000_000000000_000000000_000000000_000000000_000000000.
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Anyway, when direct casting to integer is not necessary, and the only reason you need this scientifically denoted number is about comparing it with any other numbers that might come to your system, then "soft comparison" is what you are looking for:

```
3> 1.0e6 =:= 1000000.
false
4> 1.0e6 == 1000000. 
true
```

The `==` is used to compare any two Erlang terms by their values, while `=:=` is a strict comparison. So, by the value and the exact type!